# Derive window.self from object

Tags: javascript

is there a way to get window.self of an unknown iframe (same domain) with the only reference: an object within the iframe (a div). holding thumbs for this one

Comment: Do you think you can clarify the question a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element.ownerDocument.defaultView` in Firefox.

`element.ownerDocument.parentWindow` in IE.

But Webkit (Safari) apparently doesn't support either of those things, so to get your page to work in Safari, you have to use [this amazing hack](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleParentWindow).

Comment: thanks jason - this is what im looking for - shot.
By the way - the amazing hack - seems to be for older safari

..but WebKit? did initially not do that. So in old versions of Safari there is no property to do this so we use a hack that...

Answer (score 0):

If the script is running within the iframe, then just do `window`. If the script is running outside of the iframe, then follow Jason's advice.

If you need a reference take a look at the [Gecko DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Gecko_DOM_Reference) and [MS Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050%28VS.85%29.aspx).